# How can I create a checkbox that has an editable list inside its object? (image included)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, checkbox

I'm trying to add into a modal-- a checkbox that when checked, it gives the user the ability to add/remove an inputted/typed line to the list. Each line can be removed 'x' or add another line with '+'. I have looked into HTML5 form controls, but it's hard to find an obvious way to implement this.

I apologize for the poor description, this wireframe might better explain:

[image]

I'd really appreciate some help! Thanks.

Comment: The obvious question comes up, what have you tried so far, where are you stuck, what potential frameworks are you using?

Comment: Of course a checkbox input element can not have a list "inside" it. You want a checkbox and a separate list - and then make the list show only then the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I have only looked into HTML5 form controls. I'm using angular/bootstrap/jquery/js. The reason I'm asking this is because it's proving to be difficult to find a solution when I've never created a form control like this before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way you could do it in vanilla JavaScript could be like this. I didn't see before typing that you added angular to your requirements, but I thought you could still see how it could potentially be done :)

```js
function addRow( targetSelector ) {
  var newElem = document.createElement('input');
  newElem.type = 'text';
  newElem.placeholder = 'Enter your description';
  newElem.addEventListener('blur', function( e ) {
    if (!e.target.value) {
      // no text entered removes the inputbox
      e.target.parentNode.removeChild( e.target );
      return;
    }
    var text = e.target.value;
    e.target.type = 'checkbox';
    e.target.value = text;
    e.target.setAttribute('checked', true);
    var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerText = text;
    label.for = newElem;
    var row = document.createElement('div');
    row.appendChild( e.target );
    row.appendChild( label );
    var buttonRemove = document.createElement('button');
    buttonRemove.type = 'button';
    buttonRemove.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.target.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);
    });
    buttonRemove.innerText = 'remove';
    row.appendChild(buttonRemove); 
    document.querySelector( targetSelector ).appendChild( row );
  });
  document.querySelector( targetSelector ).appendChild( newElem );
  newElem.focus();
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
  <label>Qualifications</label>
  <fieldset id="qualifications">
    <div id="added-qualifications">
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="addRow('#added-qualifications')">Add</button>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow thank you! Is there a more concise way to write this function with angular?!

Comment: @Kode_12 Yeah, I guess a directive with its own controller could do the trick, however, from your question I have no idea how your data structure is implemented or how you would want to implement it, the vanilla implementation was just a bit of fun ;)